# How to grant a user the rights to access to all new (future) databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

On my development machine, I often create new web instances that all run as `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`. I want to grant this account rights to access all new databases that I create in the future in my SQL Server 2008 R2 instance. I want to do this because it is too much of a hassle to grant rights to new databases every time I create a new web site.

Comment: @Kin This works. Should I remove the question?

Comment: Please leave it .. no need to delete. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - there is a bigger question regarding why you are using NT Authority\Network, but I asked a similar question ages ago 
[Permissions on New Databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84480/is-there-a-way-to-grant-select-for-every-database-including-new-ones-at-a-serv)
So in theory, it is fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking out the other question. Is there any problem with using `NETWORK SERVICE` as the identity of my IIS application pools?